# Moment JS not saving in utc time and then not returning local

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having some trouble with my time recording function of my app..

So I have a button that basically says start and that calls a function to store the time the button was pressed in utc time like so..

```
this.startTime = moment().utc();
```

now If I console.log(this.startTime) I get this..

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: 
Tue Oct 09 2018 10:14:01 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time), …}
_d: Tue Oct 09 2018 10:14:01 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
...
```

so it says UTC is true, but the time is 10:14 Australian Eastern Daylight Time, shouldnt this of been converted to the UTC time??

Now when I call another function that gets the time that was stored I get the correct UTC time but in Australian Eastern Daylight Time

```
let startTime = moment(startTime);
```

what I get returned is

```
_a: (7) [2018, 9, 8, 23, 5, 32, 774]
_d: Mon Oct 08 2018 23:05:32 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) {}
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSS"
_i: "2018-10-08T23:05:32.774"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: [ZoneTask]
_isValid: true
...
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

**EDIT**

if I console.log(moment.utc().format()) I get this date string

2018-10-08T23:54:23Z

but If I console.log(moment.utc()) I get this date object

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: 
Tue Oct 09 2018 10:56:56 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time), …}
_d: Tue Oct 09 2018 10:56:56 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run Moment `2.22.2` in Node.js using:

```
var startTime = moment.utc()
console.log(startTime);
// Returns moment.utc("2018-10-08T23:36:43.363+00:00")
console.log(moment(startTime));
// Returns moment.utc("2018-10-08T23:36:43.363+00:00")
console.log(moment(startTime).format());
// Returns 2018-10-08T23:45:43Z
```

Since moment returns an instance of itself you need to format your responses to a plain string using the `format()` method.

Comment: Please see my edit, when I console.log(moment.utc()) I get the local time but If I format it I get the utc time

Comment: If you `console.log` moment without formatting it first you will get the moment instance created and attached to that memory space which contains the moment object.  Seen here: https://jsbin.com/zifefaqose/edit?html,console.  In order to actually return the UTC time you will need to format the response.

Comment: This allows Moment to continue working with the object if you needed to make additional changes to it later down the line.  When you want to return what you've calculated you simply use `format()` to transform the moment object into a string. See the docs here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/